# Alternative for querying DownloadManager Android

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, download-manager

I am using system Download Manager to download some files in my app. 
To check download status, I query download manager by filtering the enqueue Id.

The problem is when I force stop Download Manager, I will not be able to query the Download Manager.

So Is there an alternative to get the status of the downloading file apart from querying Download Manager?

Comment: That means if you force stop download manager, then again it is not start querying?

Comment: The cursor will return empty when I force stop DM. So Ill not be not able to query. Once I enable Download manager again, the query works. I need to know the status when the DM is force stopped. Can I achieve this in anyway ?

Comment: I think you can not trigger that download manager is forced stopped. We need to think some other way.

Comment: Yes exactly! Any other idea ?

Comment: Lets do some research, no other way actually...haha @Smitha

Comment: Found anything useful? @Smitha Nandish

Comment: Nope.. Having an In-app download manager is what I can think of.

Comment: BUt in case of force stop, problem will be there as per I read on google. Or you have to create your own with sticky service so after force closing your functionalities will work. @Smitha Nandish

Comment: Even I got same results from google. However, Sticky service is not required if I use in-app download manager using HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Then try to use it, may be you would get success.